# Ignore imaginary roots in sympy

Tags: python, math, sympy

I'm using sympy to solve a polynomial:

```
x = Symbol('x')
y = solve(int(row["scaleA"])*x**3 + int(row["scaleB"])*x**2 + int(row["scaleC"])*x + int(row["scaleD"]), x)
```

y is a list of possible solutions. However, I need to ignore the imaginary ones and only use the real solutions. Also, I would like the solution as a value not an expression. Right now it looks like:

```
[-2/3 - 55**(1/3)*(-1/2 - sqrt(3)*I/2)/3, -2/3 - 55**(1/3)*(-1/2 + sqrt(3)*I/2)/3, -55**(1/3)/3 - 2/3]
```

I need the last expression's value (-2.22756). Are there functions in sympy to simplify this?

Comment: SymPy is most probably not the right library to use if you are interested only in float/double approximation of the root. If you use numpy/scipy you will probably get better performance and simpler code. And if you choose sympy over numpy/scipy because it is smaller you can get even smaller with mpmath which is used inside sympy for numerics (of arbitrary precision not limited by the machine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Krastonov had mentioned mpmath provided an easier method:

```
y = polyroots([int(row["scaleA"]), int(row["scaleB"]), int(row["scaleC"]), int(row["scaleD"])-value])
for root in y:
   if "j" not in str(root):
       value = root
```

Answer (score 16):

If you set `x` to be real, SymPy will only give you the real solutions

```
x = Symbol('x', real=True)
solve(..., x)
```

Comment: I am trying to solve an equation using this method but it still returns imaginary solutions

Comment: Are you using solve? Note that the new `solveset` ignores assumptions set on Symbols (use `solveset(domain=S.Reals)` to solve in the real domain. If you are using solve, this is a bug which should be [reported](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/new).

Comment: I tried both: solve, with the assumptions, solveset and solveset with domain=S.Reals.
Solve was simply skipping the assumptions on the variable to be solved (as solveset) arriving to the solutions in 30 seconds, while solveset with a domain was not able to arrive to the solution in 20 minutes. Could it be a duplicate? (https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/9973)

Answer (score 10):

`solve()`  doesn’t have a consistent output for various types of solutions, please use  `solveset(Eq,x,domain=S.Reals)` :

```
 from sympy import ImageSet, S 
 x = Symbol('x')
 y = solveset(int(row["scaleA"])*x**3 + int(row["scaleB"])*x**2+int(row["scaleC"])*x + int(row["scaleD"]), x, domain=S.Reals)
```

http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solveset.html

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly the sort of thing that `real_roots` is made for and is especially applicable to your case where the coefficients are integers:

```
x = Symbol('x')
eq = int(row["scaleA"])*x**3 + int(row["scaleB"])*x**2 + int(row["scaleC"])*x + int(row["scaleD"])
y = real_roots(eq, x)  # gives [CRootOf(...), ...]
```

The value of CRootOf instances can be evaluated to whatever precision you need and should not contain any imaginary part. For example,

```
>>> [i.n(12) for i in real_roots(3*x**3 - 2*x**2 + 7*x - 9, x)]
[1.07951904858]
```

Note: As I recall, solve will send back roots that it wasn't able to confirm met the assumptions (i.e. if they weren't found to be false for the assumption then they are returned). Also, if you want more consistent output from solve, @PyRick, set the flag `dict=True`.

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of complex numbers with just SymPy (without mpmath) use `solve` with `expand_complex` or `realroots` as mentioned above by @smichr.

```
from sympy import *
x = var("x")

# With symbol p:
p = var("p", positive=True)
# Without symbol p:
p = 1

a, b, c, d = 1, 15, 10, 1
term = p * (a*x**3 + b*x**2 + c*x + d)

pprint("\nSolution 1:")
sol = solve(term, x)
for x in sol:
    pprint(x)
    tmp = expand_complex(x)
    pprint(tmp)
    pprint(N(tmp))

pprint("\nSolution 2:")
sol = real_roots(term, x)
for x in sol:
    pprint(N(x))
```

With **symbols**, use `solve` with `expand_complex`.

Answer (score -3):

I managed to simply ignore solutions containing the character `"I"` and used `.evalf()` to evaluate the expression. The code is now:

```
    x = Symbol('x')
    y = solve(int(row["scaleA"])*x**3 + int(row["scaleB"])*x**2 + int(row["scaleC"])*x + int(row["scaleD"]), x)
    for root in y:
        if "I" not in str(root):
            print("This One:" + str(root.evalf()))
```

Comment: A better way to filter out real roots is to check `root.is_real`.