# Can't constrain SymPy variables to real numbers

Tags: python, sympy

SymPy is giving me complex solutions, even when I constrain my variables to be real, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210704/ignore-imaginary-roots-in-sympy#17871177).

Here's an example finding the intersection of a unit sphere and the plane X=1. There should be exactly 1 real solution, (1,0,0).

```
>>> import sympy
>>> x,y,z = sympy.symbols('x,y,z', real=True)
>>> list(sympy.solve([x**2 + y**2 + z**2 - 1, x - 1], [x,y,z]))
[(1, -I*z, z), (1, I*z, z)]
```

These are correct, but not real.

I can't use `solveset(…, domain=S.Reals)` because solveset doesn't seem to support systems of equations.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be open issue of sympy and known problem:
https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/9973

You could probably hack a function that checks whether there is a real solution using a heuristic - for each complex part, it will solve the equation setting the complex part to 0). This might lead to branching and a lot of work if the solutions are not simple though.