# How to plot the result of a solved equation in sympy?

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy, solver

I have an equation,

`(1 - y)/y^4 = x^2`

and I need to plot y(x).  I have solved it using this snippet:

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve

x, y = symbols('x y')
equation = Eq((y-1)*y**(-4), x**2)

solution = solve(equation, y)
print(solution)
```

And I get this monolith of an output:

```
[Piecewise((-sqrt(-(-1/x**4)**(1/3))/2 - sqrt((-1/x**4)**(1/3) - 2/(x**2*sqrt(-(-1/x**4)**(1/3))))/2, Eq(x**(-2), 0)), (-sqrt(2*(sqrt(-1/(27*x**6) + 1/(256*x**8)) + 1/(16*x**4))**(1/3) + 2/(3*x**2*(sqrt(-1/(27*x**6) + 1/(256*x**8)) + 1/(16*x**4))**(1/3)))/2 - sqrt(-2*(sqrt(-1/(27*x**6) + 1/(256*x**8)) + 1/(16*x**4))**(1/3) - 2/(x**2*sqrt(2*(sqrt(-1/(27*x**6) + 1/(256*x**8)) + 1/(16*x**4))**(1/3) + 2/(3*x**2*(sqrt(-1/(27*x**6) + 1/(256*x**8)) + 1/(16*x**4))**(1/3)))) - 2/(3*x**2*(sqrt(-1/(27*x**6) + 1/(256*x**8)) + 1/(16*x**4))**(1/3)))/2, True)), Piecewise((-sqrt(-(-1/x**4)**(1/3))/2 + sqrt((-1/x**4)**(1/3) - 2/(x**2*sqrt(-(-1/x**4)**(1/3))))/2, Eq(x**(-2), 0)), (-sqrt(2*(sqrt(-1/(27*x**6) + 1/(256*x**8)) + 1/(16*x**4))**(1/3) + 2/(3*x**2*(sqrt(-1/(27*x**6) + 1/(256*x**8)) + 1/(16*x**4))**(1/3)))/2 + sqrt(-2*(sqrt(-1/(27*x**6) + 1/(256*x**8)) + 1/(16*x**4))**(1/3) - 2/(x**2*sqrt(2*(sqrt(-1/(27*x**6) + 1/(256*x**8)) + 1/(16*x**4))**(1/3) + 2/(3*x**2*(sqrt(-1/(27*x**6) + 1/(256*x**8)) + 1/(16*x**4))**(1/3)))) - 2/(3*x**2*(sqrt(-1/(27*x**6) + 1/(256*x**8)) + 1/(16*x**4))**(1/3)))/2, True)), Piecewise((sqrt(-(-1/x**4)**(1/3))/2 - sqrt((-1/x**4)**(1/3) + 2/(x**2*sqrt(-(-1/x**4)**(1/3))))/2, Eq(x**(-2), 0)), (sqrt(2*(sqrt(-1/(27*x**6) + 1/(256*x**8)) + 1/(16*x**4))**(1/3) + 2/(3*x**2*(sqrt(-1/(27*x**6) + 1/(256*x**8)) + 1/(16*x**4))**(1/3)))/2 - sqrt(-2*(sqrt(-1/(27*x**6) + 1/(256*x**8)) + 1/(16*x**4))**(1/3) + 2/(x**2*sqrt(2*(sqrt(-1/(27*x**6) + 1/(256*x**8)) + 1/(16*x**4))**(1/3) + 2/(3*x**2*(sqrt(-1/(27*x**6) + 1/(256*x**8)) + 1/(16*x**4))**(1/3)))) - 2/(3*x**2*(sqrt(-1/(27*x**6) + 1/(256*x**8)) + 1/(16*x**4))**(1/3)))/2, True)), Piecewise((sqrt(-(-1/x**4)**(1/3))/2 + sqrt((-1/x**4)**(1/3) + 2/(x**2*sqrt(-(-1/x**4)**(1/3))))/2, Eq(x**(-2), 0)), (sqrt(2*(sqrt(-1/(27*x**6) + 1/(256*x**8)) + 1/(16*x**4))**(1/3) + 2/(3*x**2*(sqrt(-1/(27*x**6) + 1/(256*x**8)) + 1/(16*x**4))**(1/3)))/2 + sqrt(-2*(sqrt(-1/(27*x**6) + 1/(256*x**8)) + 1/(16*x**4))**(1/3) + 2/(x**2*sqrt(2*(sqrt(-1/(27*x**6) + 1/(256*x**8)) + 1/(16*x**4))**(1/3) + 2/(3*x**2*(sqrt(-1/(27*x**6) + 1/(256*x**8)) + 1/(16*x**4))**(1/3)))) - 2/(3*x**2*(sqrt(-1/(27*x**6) + 1/(256*x**8)) + 1/(16*x**4))**(1/3)))/2, True))]
```

I would like to plot it over the bounds `0 <= y <= 1`, and `0 <= x <= some_large_number`.  I haven't been able to figure out how to do it, but I'm sure it's got to be easy for me, if a PITA for my CPU.

Also, it is of no interest to me to solve this analytically.  I would be only too delighted to do it numerically, but I don't know how to do that either.  Sympy was just a solution that presented itself to me.

Answer (score 0):

Sympy seems to be [mixing in complex solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210704/ignore-imaginary-roots-in-sympy). I'm unsure how to cope with them in this case. Note that for `y` smaller than 1, the LHS is negative, so never equal to the square of a real number.

If, however, you are mostly interested in a plot, [`plot_implicit`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html#sympy.plotting.plot_implicit.plot_implicit) can come in handy:

```py
from sympy import symbols, Eq
from sympy.plotting import plot_implicit

x, y = symbols('x y') # symbols('x y', real=True, positive=True) doesn't seem to make a difference
equation = Eq(((y - 1) * y ** (-4)), x ** 2)

plot_implicit(equation)
```

[image: example plot]

PS: To find the rightmost point of the curve, differentiating the left-hand side  `solve(equation.lhs.diff())` gives the solution `y = 4/3`, corresponding to `x = 2*sqrt(3)/3`. Finding numerical solutions for `y >= 1` is straightforward. `nsolve` can find a numerical solution for a given `x0` smaller than `2*sqrt(3)/3`, e.g. `nsolve(equation.subs(x, .1), 1)` gives `1.01042350456793`.

Comment: Does this answer your question?